# What if the Twilio Browser Client user is afk? How to change a Ready device to Not Ready?

Tags: twilio

I must be missing something.

I've successfully set my web page so that the browser is ready to receive incoming calls using the code from the [Twilio QuickStart guides](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client/incoming-calls), but I wanted to give my user the ability to set their status to "Not Ready to Take Calls" if they're afk for example.

Is there a way to do this?

I've looked at the documentation and the closest thing I can find is:

```
Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
```

But disconnectAll doesn't prevent incoming calls.

I'm wanting something like the ability to set Presence but there's only a method to register a callback when a Client's Presence changes:

```
Twilio.Device.presence(function(presenceEvent) {...});
```

And Presence currently only changes when a Client is on another call. I want the Client to be able to set Presence to a state that means incoming calls aren't directed to it.